# Redis logrotate config

Tags: redis, logrotate

Does anyone have a sample logrotate config for redis?  This is what I have so far

```
/var/log/redis/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                ...
        endscript
}
```

But I'm not sure what to do on the postrotate step.  This is on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will probably suffice:

```
/var/log/redis/*.log {
       weekly
       rotate 10
       copytruncate
       delaycompress
       compress
       notifempty
       missingok
}
```

Comment: But how does this request Redis to re-open the log file?
... Oops, I figured it out myself: Redis actually reopens at each log line (see https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/337#issuecomment-4002868)

Comment: copytruncate reuses the same original file(copy then truncate). So even if redis didn't reopen the file it should have been working ok.

Comment: Copytruncate is inefficient, and I'd like to avoid it if possible.  Is it possible?  Looks like it is, so I'll try it.

Comment: Copytruncate doesn't seem to work for redis-sentinel. The log doesn't grow for Sentinel after truncation.

Answer (score 4):

I went with

```
/var/log/redis/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0660 redis redis
}
```

because I don't want `copytruncate`.

I'm not sure the `create` line is necessary.  It matches the file mode and ownership of the log files typically created by redis-server on Ubuntu (or Debian).